# What does the CanvasRenderingContext2D function do?

Tags: javascript, canvas

What does the `CanvasRenderingContext2D` function do? I do know that it has a property called `prototype` (`CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype`) which has stuff like `fillRect()` and stuff. But, `CanvasRenderingContext2D` is a function object, so what is the use of `CanvasRenderingContext2D`? I am unable to find anything on the internet about this, so here is the question

**Edit:** Seems like people think this question is about doing stuff like `*canvas*.getContext("2d")`. The question is ***What is the purpose of `CanvasRenderingContext2D` as a function itself?***

**Edit2:** `CanvasRenderingContext2D` is a function object. Try `typeof CanvasRenderingContext2D` which returns `"function"`. So, what's the use of this function?

Comment: The purpose is to provide the implementation for `CanvasRenderingContext2D`. It can't be used directly, only through the web API methods as you have already been told.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question, you are wondering why this happens:

```
typeof CanvasRenderingContext2D
// => "function"
```

This is just a quirk of JavaScript. All classes will do this, for example:

```
typeof class MyClass {}
// => "function"
```

`typeof` will never return "class", even though that might make more sense. You can see all the possible return values here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof

Comment: I do know how it works lol. I am trying to know how `CanvasRenderingContext2D` is used as a function.

Answer (score 1):

To have a defined instance of `CanvasRenderingContext2D` you need to have an html `<canvas id="canvas" height="100" width="100"></canvas>` element. To then make use of 2d canvas context you need to call the `getContext()` function on the `<canvas>` element and use `'2d'` as the context argument. It should look like this basically.

```
<canvas id="canvas" height="100" width="100"></canvas>
const c = document.getElementById("canvas"); //Makes looking at the code a little nicer
const ctx = c.getContext('2d');
```

Now from here you can do `ctx.fillRect()` `ctx.stroke()` `ctx.fillStyle()` any 2d context functions you want to use.
The `CanvasRenderingContext2D` is just an interface the Canvas API uses to draw things onto this 2d surface and is full of properties and functions to assist you in making 2d images/frames
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D

Answer (score 0):

In javascript classes are functions. You wouldn't do this in this case, but it's the constructor for the class: `new CanvasRenderingContext2D()`.

```js
class Test {}
console.log(typeof Test); // function

const t = new Test();
console.log(typeof t); // object
```

Answer (score 0):

In real situation if you wanna check type use this :
(In case that you are not sure or var is not defined at the moment)

```js
    if(ctx instanceof CanvasRenderingContext2D == false) return;

    ctx.fillRect( 0 , 0 , 100 , 100)
```